# How to fire UIElement.TouchDown event on Windows Forms C# on Touchscreen, windows 8

Tags: c#, winforms, events

This need to be Windows Forms (winforms) - not WPF. Problem is with single MouseDown event that didn't fire properly on touchscreen on windows 8. MouseDown fire either after touch and move finger or after click - it fire just after you get off your finger. I want to fire it like a normal MouseDown should - after i touch the screen. The solution to that would be that TouchDown event. But, i just cant to handle that event. What I do is that I create class Multitouch like that:

```
class Moultitouch : UIElement
{
    public Moultitouch()
    {
        this.TouchDown += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.TouchEventArgs>(Moultitouch_TouchDown);
    }

    void Moultitouch_TouchDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        //it never goes in
    }

    protected override void OnTouchDown(System.Windows.Input.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTouchDown(e);
    }
}
```

After that I'm declaring that class in my component which on Touch should handle that event. I did a lot of research on that and 've been trying to do that and nothing so far. I think that "Hosting a WPF Composite Control in Windows Forms" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx could solve my problem but that solution could be really long and tough. Any help or ideas are really appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. What is your question?

Comment: Right, in more simple way. I think that we can reduce that problem to a simple winform with one button on it. I want to handle UIElement.TouchDown by touching it on touchscreen. How can I do this? May be now you will understand more of what i said before.

Comment: There's no such thing as `UIElement` in winforms. I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that touchscreen fired events and mouse fired events are not the same thing. For example a Winform button can toggle its background colour by handling OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave. Code that up on a form and run the cursor in and out of the button and everything works fine. Use a touch screen and run your finger over it in the same way and nothing happens until you release contact with the screen, and then a click event is raised. Not the answer you are looking for, but I am having the same issue with an on-screen keyboard I'm developing for a disabled friend of mine. My research led me here https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/05/25/uwp-evolution-touch-development/#02octDx0X3uBHXqm.97 and specifically to the links that provide detail on the ManipulationStarted and ManipulationEnded events. Hope that helps, it has for what I'm trying to achieve.